# Getting pixel data from UIImageView -- works on simulator, not device

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, pixel

Based on the responses to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144250/how-to-get-the-rgb-values-for-a-pixel-on-an-image-on-the-iphone), I've created a category on UIImageView for extracting pixel data. This works fine in the simulator, but not when deployed to the device. I should say not *always* -- the odd thing is that it does fetch the correct pixel colour if point.x == point.y; otherwise, it gives me pixel data for a pixel on the other side of that line, as if mirrored. (So a tap on a pixel in the lower-right corner of the image gives me the pixel data for a corresponding pixel in the upper-left, but tapping on a pixel in the lower-left corner returns the correct pixel colour). The touch coordinates (CGPoint) are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
@interface UIImageView (PixelColor)
- (UIColor*)getRGBPixelColorAtPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end

@implementation UIImageView (PixelColor)

- (UIColor*)getRGBPixelColorAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    UIColor* color = nil;

    CGImageRef cgImage = [self.image CGImage];
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
    NSUInteger x = (NSUInteger)floor(point.x);
    NSUInteger y = height - (NSUInteger)floor(point.y);

    if ((x < width) && (y < height))
    {
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
        CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
        const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);
        size_t offset = ((width * y) + x) * 4;
        UInt8 red = data[offset];
        UInt8 blue = data[offset+1];
        UInt8 green = data[offset+2];
        UInt8 alpha = data[offset+3];
        CFRelease(bitmapData);
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f];
    }

    return color;
}
```

Comment: can you check the value of self.image.imageOrientation?  it's possible that the image you're using is in UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored which would be the reflection you're seeing, though I don't know why it would be that way only on the device....

Comment: It's UIImageOrientationUp on both simulator and device. I'm not sure that "left mirrored" is the correct interpretation of what's happening, because the reflection is (seemingly) taking place along the diagonal y=x, and UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored is a simple rotation of the entire image "90 deg CCW" according to the SDK.

Comment: More info: if I swap how x and y are being calculated, the behaviour is reversed -- it works on the device, but not on the simulator. (Although the exact positioning on the device seems to be off by a few degrees CCW, but it could be the imprecision of my finger versus using the mouse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think R **B G** is wrong. You have:

```
UInt8 red =   data[offset];     
UInt8 blue =  data[offset+1];
UInt8 green = data[offset+2];
```

But don't you really mean R **G B**? :

```
UInt8 red =   data[offset];     
UInt8 green = data[offset+1];
UInt8 blue =  data[offset+2];
```

But even with that fixed there's still a problem as it turns out Apple [byte swaps](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html) (great article) the R and B values when on the device, but **not** when on the simulator.

I had a similar simulator/device issue with a PNG's pixel buffer returned by CFDataGetBytePtr.

This resolved the issue for me:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        UInt8 red =   data[offset];
        UInt8 green = data[offset + 1];
        UInt8 blue =  data[offset + 2];
#else
        //on device
        UInt8 blue =  data[offset];       //notice red and blue are swapped
        UInt8 green = data[offset + 1];
        UInt8 red =   data[offset + 2];
#endif
```

Not sure if this will fix your issue, but your misbehaving code looks close to what mine looked like before I fixed it.

One last thing: I believe the simulator will let you access your pixel buffer `data[]` even after `CFRelease(bitmapData)` is called. On the device this is **not** the case in my experience. Your code shouldn't be affected, but in case this helps someone else I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Took me some time to finally get back to this, but your code was bang-on. The combination of mixing up G and B, and not knowing about the byte ordering change Xcode does behind the scenes, was a fatal combination.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following alternative approach:

- create a CGBitmapContext
- draw the image into the context
- call CGBitmapContextGetData on the context to get the underlying data
- work out your offset into the raw data (based on how you created the bitmap context)
- extract the value

This approach works for me on the simulator and device.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that because of the overhead involved (this function could be called more than one a second)

Comment: You could cache the raw data, then the overhead is reduced to an array lookup, unless the image is continually changing.

Comment: That's true. However, I still would like to know what the underlying problem is in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that in the code posted in the original questions instead of:

```
NSUInteger x = (NSUInteger)floor(point.x);
NSUInteger y = height - (NSUInteger)floor(point.y);
```

It should be:

```
NSUInteger x = (NSUInteger)floor(point.x);
NSUInteger y = (NSUInteger)floor(point.y);
```