# iOS 5 + GLKView: How to access pixel RGB data for colour-based vertex picking?

Tags: colors, ios5, opengl-es-2.0, pixel, picking

I've been converting my own personal OGLES 2.0 framework to take advantage of the functionality added by the new iOS 5 framework `GLKit`.

After pleasing results, I now wish to implement the colour-based picking mechanism described [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php?color1). For this, you must access the back buffer to retrieve a touched pixel RGBA value, which is then used as a unique identifier for a vertex/primitive/display object. Of course, this requires temporary unique coloring of all vertices/primitives/display objects.

I have two questions, and I'd be very grateful for assistance with either:

> 1. I have access to a `GLKViewController`, `GLKView`, `CAEAGLLayer` (of the `GLKView`) and an `EAGLContext`. I also have access to all OGLES 2.0
>      buffer related commands. How do I combine these to identify the color
>      of a pixel in the EAGLContext I'm tapping on-screen?
> 2. Given that I'm using Vertex Buffer Objects to do my rendering, is there a neat way to override the colour provided to my vertex shader
>      which firstly doesn't involve modifying buffered vertex (colour)
>      attributes, and secondly doesn't involve the addition of an IF
>      statement into the vertex shader?

I assume the answer to (2) is "no", but for reasons of performance and non-arduous code revamping I thought it wise to check with someone more experienced.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received. Thank you for your time

**UPDATE**

Well I now know how to read pixel data from the active frame buffer using [glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml). So I guess I just have to do the special "unique colours" render to the back buffer, briefly switch to it and read pixels, then switch back. This will inevitably create a visual flicker, but I guess it's the easiest way; certainly quicker (and more sensible) than creating a `CGImageContextRef` from a screen snapshot and analyzing that way.

Still, any tips as regards the back buffer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I've worked out exactly how to do this as concisely as possible. Below I explain how to achieve this and list all the code required :)

In order to allow touch interaction to select a pixel, first add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `GLKViewController` subclass (assuming you want tap-to-select-pixel), with the following target method inside that class. You must make your `GLKViewController` subclass a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`:

```
@interface GLViewController : GLKViewController <GLKViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

After instantiating your gesture recognizer, add it to the `view` property (which in `GLKViewController` is actually a `GLKView`):

```
// Inside GLKViewController subclass init/awakeFromNib:
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:[self tapRecognizer]];
[[self tapRecognizer] setDelegate:self];
```

Set the target action for your gesture recognizer; you can do this when creating it using a particular `init...` however I created mine using Storyboard (aka "the new Interface Builder in Xcode 4.2") and wired it up that way.

Anyway, here's my target action for the tap gesture recognizer:

```
-(IBAction)onTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    const CGPoint loc = [recognizer locationInView:[self view]];
    [self pickAtX:loc.x Y:loc.y];
}
```

The pick method called in there is one I've defined inside my `GLKViewController` subclass:

```
-(void)pickAtX:(GLuint)x Y:(GLuint)y {
    GLKView *glkView = (GLKView*)[self view];
    UIImage *snapshot = [glkView snapshot];
    [snapshot pickPixelAtX:x Y:y];
}
```

This takes advantage of a handy new method `snapshot` that Apple kindly included in `GLKView` to produce a `UIImage` from the underlying `EAGLContext`.

What's important to note is a comment in the `snapshot` API documentation, which states:

> This method should be called whenever your application explicitly
>   needs the contents of the view; never attempt to directly read the
>   contents of the underlying framebuffer using OpenGL ES functions.

This gave me a clue as to why my earlier attempts to invoke `glReadPixels` in attempts to access pixel data generated an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, and the indicator that sent me down the right path instead.

You'll notice in my `pickAtX:Y:` method defined a moment ago I call a `pickPixelAtX:Y:` on the `UIImage`. This is a method I added to `UIImage` in a custom category:

```
@interface UIImage (NDBExtensions)
-(void)pickPixelAtX:(NSUInteger)x Y:(NSUInteger)y;
@end
```

Here is the implementation; it's the final code listing required. The code came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911360/getting-pixel-data-from-uiimageview-works-on-simulator-not-device) and has been amended according to the answer received there:

```
@implementation UIImage (NDBExtensions)

- (void)pickPixelAtX:(NSUInteger)x Y:(NSUInteger)y {

    CGImageRef cgImage = [self CGImage];
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);

    if ((x < width) && (y < height))
    {
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
        CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
        const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);
        size_t offset = ((width * y) + x) * 4;
        UInt8 b = data[offset+0];
        UInt8 g = data[offset+1];
        UInt8 r = data[offset+2];
        UInt8 a = data[offset+3];
        CFRelease(bitmapData);
        NSLog(@"R:%i G:%i B:%i A:%i",r,g,b,a);
    }
}

@end
```

I originally tried some related code found in an Apple API doc entitled: "Getting the pixel data from a CGImage context" which required 2 method definitions instead of this 1, but much more code is required and there is data of type `void *` for which I was unable to implement the correct interpretation.

That's it! Add this code to your project, then upon tapping a pixel it will output it in the form:

```
R:24 G:46 B:244 A:255
```

Of course, you should write some means of extracting those RGBA int values (which will be in the range 0 - 255) and using them however you want. One approach is to return a `UIColor` from the above method, instantiated like so:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f];
```

Comment: I've finished the whole picking mechanism now and it works a treat :) Huzzah!

Comment: The selected answer works great, except in it also seems to have revealed a significant bug in Apple's GLKView **snapshot** method that causes big memory allocation spikes and leads to crashes in my case... if anyone else has run into this issue, please see my <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354982/glkviews-snapshot-method-causes-huge-memory-spikes-looking-for-alternatives">new post</a> on the subject.