# testing for taps on graphics drawn in a UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, opacity, alpha

I have drawn a non-rectangular shape into a UIView subclass using core graphics. Now I want to make this shape "tappable", but not the areas of the UIView that is transparent. IE the UIView subclass background color is alpha 0. When the user taps off of the graphic itself, but still on the view, how do I test this so I can do an appropriate action, or not?

Comment: There may be other ways but the only way I can think of for this to work is to test if px color != background color (or test alpha). There are some Q+As here @ getting px color.

Comment: Thanks. I am searching for those Q and As now.

Comment: Some details in the links here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616778/ios-detect-the-color-of-a-pixel

Comment: [this will help you](http://buildmobile.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d-part-4/)