# Find out which type of area you are in from MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

is there any way to determine which type of area you are in from a MKMapView? I.e. if the centre of the map is in the ocean we can tell the user: the centre of the map is above the ocean, or if the map is centred above a green area: the centre of the map is above parkland...

The only way I can think of to do this is to create a screenshot of the visible screen and analyse the colour of each bit by using some method such as this: [iOS -- detect the color of a pixel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616778/ios-detect-the-color-of-a-pixel)

However I would be interested to know if there is an easier way that anyone can think of!

EDIT

To make it more clear what I'm looking for, I'm basically looking for a way to turn a section of a map into a top down level for a game, with different areas determined by the areas of the map...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CLPlacemark` has a couple of properties: `inlandWater` and `ocean` which tell you when the placemark is in water. I think you can get a placemark from the geocoder.

It also has `areasOfInterest` which will give you parks and landmarks.

Comment: Any idea the sort of accuracy on this?

Comment: I haven't used it extensively. I used it a couple of times and it worked. The `areasOfInterest` wasn't that complete, but water seemed fine.

Comment: ok that's great cheers... I'll have a wait and see if anyone has any better idea's but if not I'll mark you correct :)

Comment: Not sure whether we're going to get any other answers... I'll mark you as correct in an hour or so, but I'll post if I find a better way myself whilst I'm mucking about with the api :)

Comment: I have accomplished this by taking a screenshot of the entire screen and then determining the colour of the centre pixel, this gives me extremely accurate results, however I have the problem that I want to do this every 0.04 seconds and taking a screenshot programatically is not a nippy process ;)

Answer (score 0):

there is no foolproof way BUT `CLGeocoder` can reverse geocode a coordinate to an address and that would give you stuff like:

0/0 = ...., ocean
51/10 = ..., germany 
-90/10  = ..... , united states

and so on

Comment: note the numbers are amade up -- I cant geocode in my head :D

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm looking for a bit more of an accurate method i.e. determining whether a point is above a road or whether it is on the buildings beside the road.. e.t.c :/ but thanks for the tip!