# iOS programatic screenshot of single pixel

Tags: ios, screenshot, getpixel

I am trying to get the RGBA colour of a single pixel programatically on an iOS device. I currently have a method, however it involves taking a screenshot of the whole screen and then finding the RGB colour of the central pixel, because I want to find the central pixel every time-step of the game this causes a large lag in the performance of the app whilst the screenshot is generated. For this reason I wish to take a screenshot of only a single pixel of the screen but cannot find a method for this anywhere online... Here is my current method:

```
UIImage *screenImage = [self screenshot];

CGPoint pointToCheck = CGPointMake(0.5 , 0.5);

UIColor *color = [self colorFromImage:screenImage sampledAtPoint:pointToCheck];

- (UIColor*)colorFromImage:(UIImage*)image sampledAtPoint:(CGPoint)p {
    CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
    CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImage);
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
    int col = p.x*(width-1);
    int row = p.y*(height-1);
    const UInt8* pixel = data + row*bytesPerRow+col*4;
    UIColor* returnColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255. green:pixel[1]/255. blue:pixel[2]/255. alpha:1.0];
    CFRelease(bitmapData);
    return returnColor;
}

- (UIImage *) screenshot
{
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Taking a step back, what are you attempting to grab the colo(u)r for? (In other words, what does the game use it for and why doesn't the game already have a copy of the underlying image data.)

Comment: @middaparka I am essentially using a MKMapView as a map for a top down game, I'm not entirely sure yet of what the game will entail, as I'm just trying to find out whether it is accomplishable at all, but it will revolve around the different areas on an iOS map. In fewer words: I want to determine whether the centre point of the map is on a road, or in a shopping mall, or in water, or in a hospital, e.t.c

Comment: The easiest way I could think of doing this (and also the only one) was to determine the colour of this pixel and then have a series of if statements to set the 'land type' dependent on the colour...

Comment: That sounds a bit optimistic. (What happens if Apple decides to change the underlying colo(u)rs in a future iOS release?)

Comment: Perhaps it is a tad optimistic, I hadn't thought of that. If only they provided some api for accessing the vector data which they use to display the map!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code here to get the color of a single pixel:

[iOS -- detect the color of a pixel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616778/ios-detect-the-color-of-a-pixel)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Funnily enough... that's the exact article I used to get the result I have at the moment :P Problem still stands that you have to take a screenshot of the whole screen each time :) But thanks anyways!

Comment: Make sure you try the second answer on that thread, the accepted answer is not always the right one :)

Comment: The second one still requires a UIImage of the whole screen, which is the process which is taking all the time :P But yeah I always make sure to try all answers given :)