# Get color from pixel in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I want to get the color from a coordination on my screen and place it in a variable. I'm using Theos and I'm just messing around on my iOS 5 device for learning so please don't start the "stop wasting your time making tweaks for old iOS" as I've seen on all my posts :|

Comment: Post some code that you have tried? No one will feed your spoon...

Comment: well, i havent done anything since i have to get the color first

Comment: Answer is already available here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616778/ios-detect-the-color-of-a-pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
// UIView+ColorOfPoint.h
@interface UIView (ColorOfPoint)
- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end

// UIView+ColorOfPoint.m
#import "UIView+ColorOfPoint.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (ColorOfPoint)

- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //NSLog(@"pixel: %d %d %d %d", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

    return color;
}
```

You can find the files here: https://github.com/ivanzoid/ikit/tree/master/UIView%2BColorOfPoint

Also, check the answers here for more info: [How to get the color of a pixel in an UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160229/how-to-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-an-uiview)