# color meter rgb iphone ios code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'd like to build from scratch a color meter for iphone: an app where you point the camera 
at something and you get the rgb values back. easy.
the app store is plenty of apps like that but i'd like to use it as case study for future explorations.

does anyone know where i can start with?
any framework already available or even better an app already built an available as opensource?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did try this earlier some time back and these two answers helped me a lot.....

[How to get the RGB values for a pixel on an image on the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144250/how-to-get-the-rgb-values-for-a-pixel-on-an-image-on-the-iphone)

[Getting RGB pixel data from CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073259/getting-rgb-pixel-data-from-cgimage)

hoping they will help you too.. :)