# Replace all solid colors in a UIImage

Tags: image, cocoa-touch, colors, replace, uiimage

I'm trying to perform image recognition via a SIFT algorithm using solid shapes.

To improve the performance, I would like to take the image (captured from an iOS camera), make all non-light colors a dark red and make the remaining pixels transparent.

An example of a before and after of what I'm trying to achieve is attached in the images on this question.

Assumption: the images are always solid-black shapes and printed on plain white paper

Can someone please help me with this or point me in the right direction?[image]

Answer (score 1):

As provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17247968/1130270) code, you can simply iterate over the pixel data and compare each color of the pixel with the value you want to filter. But before you should maybe apply some filters for better results.