# How do I restrict touches on a UIImageView to the opaque parts of its UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, hittest

I have a UIImageView with userInteractionEnabled set to YES, and a few gesture recognizers on it which let the user interact with it.  The view's image is of a shape, with the rest transparent, and I only want the opaque parts of the image to accept touches (the superview is also interactive).

I'm guessing I need to override a hit testing method, but which one and how?

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the the pixel color information on the touched point ( [How to get the RGB values for a pixel on an image on the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144250/how-to-get-the-rgb-values-for-a-pixel-on-an-image-on-the-iphone) ). May be you can test for its alpha value to determine whether it is opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the exact answer you're after, this should give you an idea of one way of achieving this. This blog entry is using the Cocoas2D framework.

http://abitofcode.com/2011/07/irregular-touch-detection-when-cgrect-is-not-enough-part-1/