# How to check if UIImage is completely transparent?

Tags: uiimage

My app is downloading images from url and sometimes these images are completely transparent with size 600 x 400 pixels or even more. I would like to detect such images and ignore them. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: There is no single method like `isFullyTransaparent`, but can perform naive check of underlying bitmap of CGImage/CIImage, pixel by pixel.

Comment: OK - thank you - I have done it using this answer
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736285/how-to-check-pixel-color-of-a-uiview-or-a-uiimage)