# Finding Bounding Box of Rotated Image that has Transparent Background

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-graphics

I have a `UIImage` that has a transparent background. When rotating this image, I'd like to find the bounding box around the graphic (ie the nons transparent part, if you rotate it in a `UIImageView`, it will find the bounding box around the entire `UIImage` including the transparent part).

Is there an Apple library that might do this for me? If not, does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your questions correctly, you can retrieve the frame (not bounds) of uiimageview then get the individual cgpoints and explicitly transform these points to get a transformed rectangle. Because in Apple's documentation it says:  *You can operate on a CGRect structure by calling the function CGRectApplyAffineTransform. This function returns the smallest rectangle that contains the transformed corner points of the rectangle passed to it.* Transforming points 1 by 1 should avoid this auto-correcting behavior.

```
CGRect originalFrame = UIImageView.frame;
CGPoint p1 = originalFrame.origin;
CGPoint p2 = p1; p2.x += originalFrame.width;
CGPoint p3 = p1; p3.y += originalFrame.height;

//Use the same transformation that you applied to uiimageview here
CGPoint transformedP1 = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(p1, transform);
CGPoint transformedP2 = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(p2, transform);
CGPoint transformedP3 = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(p3, transform);
```

Now you should be able to define a new rectangle from these 3 points (4th one is optional because width and height can be calculated from 3 points. One point to note is that you cannot store this new rectangle in a cgrect because cgrect is defined by an origin and a size so its edges are always parallel to x and y axis. Apple's cgrect definition does not allow rotated rectangles to be stored.

Comment: Thanks for the long, well thought out response. This is tough to explain. I'm not just interested in the bounding box around the rotated UIImage (you can get that from the UIImageView frame). I actually need it around the graphic that's in the UIImage. Think I probably need a bit map or something for this. Thanks taking the time though.

Comment: Then maybe you can go for smt like explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144250/how-to-get-the-rgb-values-for-a-pixel-on-an-image-on-the-iphone